# Extracting from mulit-array and putting it into my own - php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to extract data from a multidimensional array and then putting into one of my own so that I can load it into my database.

Source:

```
array( "ListOrdersResult" => 
    array ( "Orders" =>
        array( "Order" =>
            array( [0] => {
                    "Title" => $productTitle,
                    "customer_name" => $customerName,
                    "customer_id" => $customerId,
                    "random_info" => $randomInfo
                    },
                    [1] => { 
                    "Title" => $productTitle,
                    "customer_name" => $customerName,
                    "customer_id" => $customerId,
                    "random_info" => $randomInfo
                    }
                )
            )
        )
```

To do this, I'm cycling through it like this - I have no issues with extracting data. 
My code:

```
$count = count($listOrderArray['ListOrdersResult']['Orders']['Order']);

//Cycle through each Order to extract the data I want
for($i = 0; $count > $i; $i++) {
    $baseArray = $listOrderArray['ListOrdersResult']['Orders']['Order'][$i];

    foreach($baseArray as $key => $value) {
        if($key == "Title" || $key == "customer_id") {
            //ADD TO multidimensional array
        }
    }
}
```

How I'm trying to structure it.

```
array( [0] => { 
    array( 
    "Title" => $title, 
    "customer_id" => $customer_id
    },
    [1] => {
    "Title" => $nextTitle,
    "customer_id" => $next_customer_id
    }
    );
```

The ultimate goal is to make it easier to load the information into the database by gathering the data by record and then loading it to the database rather than loading by creating an new record and then coming back and modifying that record. To me that seems like it would take more resources and has a higher chance of inconsistent data, but I'm new so I could be wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to unset keys you don't want:

```
$result = array_map(function ($i) {
    unset($i['customer_name'], $i['random_info']);
    return $i;
}, $listOrderArray['ListOrdersResult']['Orders']['Order']);
```

More about [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Or you also can select the keys you want:

```
$result = array_map(function ($i) {
    return ['Title' => $i['Title'], 'customer_id' => $i['customer_id']];
}, $listOrderArray['ListOrdersResult']['Orders']['Order']);
```

---

About your code and question:

```
$count = count($listOrderArray['ListOrdersResult']['Orders']['Order']);

//Cycle through each Order to extract the data I want
for($i = 0; $count > $i; $i++) {
```

There's no reason to use a `count` and a `for` loop, use `foreach`.

```
array( [0] => { 
    array( 
    "Title" => $title, 
    "customer_id" => $customer_id
    },
    [1] => {
    "Title" => $nextTitle,
    "customer_id" => $next_customer_id
    }
    );
```

doesn't make sense, what are these curly brackets? You should write it like this if you want to be understood:

```
array(
    [0] => array( 
        "Title" => "fakeTitle0", 
        "customer_id" => "fakeCustomerId0"
    ),
    [1] => array(
        "Title" => "fakeTitle1",
        "customer_id" => "fakeCustomerId1"
    )
);
```

Comment: This was great. Thank you. I did not know about array_map and unset, these are very helpful. Before I was trying to traverse xml with SimpleXML and that was considerably more difficult until I learned of json_decode(json_encode)). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have this initial variable.

```
$listOrderArray = array(
    "ListOrdersResult" => array(
        "Orders" => array(
            "Order" => array(
                0 => array(
                    "Title" => "productTitle",
                    "customer_name" => "customerName",
                    "customer_id" => "customerId",
                    "random_info" => "randomInfo",
                ),
                1 => array(
                    "Title" => "productTitle",
                    "customer_name" => "customerName",
                    "customer_id" => "customerId",
                    "random_info" => "randomInfo",
                ),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The only thing you should do is to remove the inner array from the three outer arrays.

Here is the solution:

```
$orders = $listOrderArray['ListOrdersResult']['Orders']['Order'];
```